# Search function on a website - displaying no data

Tags: php, html, sql, search

I've created a search page but no matter how I change it I can't get it to return results even though they match up perfectly with the database. Could someone maybe be another pair of eyes and point me in the right direction?

I'm always quite unsure when putting variables in SQL statements so maybe it's an error there.

**Searchform.php**

```
<?php
include 'index.php';
?>
<html>
<center>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skeleton.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css" />
 <title>Search</title> 

<h3>Search People</h3> 
<p>You  may search either by first or last name</p> 
<form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="searchform"> 
<input  type="text" name="name"> 
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
</form>       
</html> 
</p>
</center>
```

**Search.php**

```
<?php 
    include 'pagetemplate.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
        if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
            if(preg_match("/[A-Z  | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])){ 
                $name=$_POST['name']; 
                //-query  the database table 

              $result = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$name%' OR LastName LIKE '%$name%'");
             print " Query returned ". $result->num_rows . " rows ";
             //The function to display data is below
             displayData($result);


                // $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE (FirstName LIKE ? OR LastName LIKE ? OR Username LIKE ?)';

                //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', "%$name%", "%$name%", "%$name%");

                //mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                //-run  the query against the mysql query function 


                } 
                else{ 
                    echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
                    } 
            } 
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you try changing :- `$result = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$name%' OR LastName LIKE '%$name%'");` this to this ?
`$result = $mysqli_conn->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE FirstName LIKE "%$name%" OR LastName LIKE "%$name%" ');`

Comment: Still displays a blank page! I'm using "abc" as my example and I've entered some data into the database with all abc's. Can't figure it out!

Comment: If i used the OO code I've written below that's commented out, how would I display that? thats the only reason ive not been using that part of the code as its unfinished

Comment: can u give source code of your search form

Comment: Have you determined that the script is definitely getting called, and what execution path its taking. I do that by putting `echo`s all over the place.